# Twitter bootstrap 3 form-horizontal and multiple input columns on single line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to place multiple columns of inputs in single line like this:

[image: What i need]

I did this by grouping multiple inputs in single `form-group`, but this way I can't use `has-error` class.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Quarter</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-20" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Address</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-15" />
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Addr. №</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-3" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Block name/Number</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-5" />
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Entrance</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-3" />
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Floor</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-3" />
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Apartament</label>
     <input type="text" class="col-sm-3" />
</div>
```

So is it possible to have multiple `form-group`'s  for each input box?

Comment: There is nothing like col-sm-20 in bootstrap, it uses a 12 grid system to divide the screen so u can provide values between col-sm-1 to col-sm-12

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To align easily things in bootstrap 3, You should use the [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/f3hB4/) close to your needs :

```
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Quarter</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Addr. №</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Block name/Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1">Entrance</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1">Floor</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Apartament</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

The alignment depends on the width of the screen so be sure to tune it properly to your needs. Then you can style the inputs themselves.

Comment: I can't see where `<form class="form-horizontal"></form>` and `<div class="form-group"></div>` is. I want to preserve `form-group`elements to easily bind validation.

Comment: You know you can play around with my fiddle don't you ? I have modified it for you. Is it better ?

Comment: you fiddle doesn't include `form-group` elements.

Comment: just replace .row with .form-group, the documentation says it clearly: for form-horizontal, they both work the same way

Answer (score 20):

You need to wrap the inputs in their own `col-*` classes like this..

```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Quarter</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Address</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Addr. №</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Block name/Number</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Entrance</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Floor</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Apartment</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/hviqAhBCaV)

Also, there is no `col-sm-15` or `col-sm-20` in Bootstrap

Comment: There can be whatever number of columns you like if you use SASS/LESS or play with setting on bootstrap's download page.

Comment: Of course. I assumed the OP was using the standard Bootstrap build.

Comment: In this example it's not possible to mark as error only one field in a row. Or I'm missing something.